# PHP Comparing two multidimensional arrays with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-difference

I'm attempting to compare non-matching values within two multidimensional arrays (`$allSessions`, my master array and `$userSessions`, my inner array...everything in it should be within `$allSessions`, but structured differently) and my approach was to use a foreach within a foreach loop.

This works under most situations except one (when `$userSession` only contains one item).

I'm wondering if the bug is caused by this loop within a loop? When it is buggy because $userSessions only contains 1 item, the returned `$unregistered` array contains multiples of each item...

```
    $allSessions = $this->getAllUpcoming();

    $unregistered = array();

    $userSessions = $this->getUserSessions($userID);



    foreach ($allSessions as $session) {
        foreach ($userSessions as $user) {
            if ($user["entry_data"]["session-participant-session"]["id"] !== $session["id"]){
                array_push($unregistered, $session);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: foreach just expects an array. it doesn't care if there's 0, 1, or gazillions of items. it'll just iterate over whatever's in there.

Comment: What does `$userSessions` with one item look like?

Comment: Are you ''sure'' it's working when you have more than 1 item in `$userSessions`? It looks to me like you're going to get all non-matching elements in `$userSessions` for each element in `$allSessions.`

Answer (score 0):

In the way you have it, you will get every non-matching element.

Let's say you have a perfect match of a,b,c in `$allSessions` and a,b,c in `$userSessions`. In your first outer loop you have 'a'. In the inner loop you will add 'b' and 'c' to your $unregistered because they don't match. Then you go on to 'b' in your outer loop and add 'a' and another copy of 'c' in your inner loop. And so on.

I'm pretty you're going to have to structure it differently. You've got to check *every* element in `$userSessions` and go on to the next element in `$allSessions` only if you don't find any matches:

```
foreach ($allSessions as $session) {
    foreach ($userSessions as $user) {
        if ($user["entry_data"]["session-participant-session"]["id"] === $session["id"])
            continue 2; // this goes to the next element in $allSessions
    }
    array_push($unregistered, $session);
}
```

A slightly more readable form if you are not familiar with `continue`:

```
foreach ($allSessions as $session) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($userSessions as $user) {
        if ($user["entry_data"]["session-participant-session"]["id"] === $session["id"]) {
            $found = true;
            break; // an optimization - not strictly necessary
        }
    }
    if (!$found)
        array_push($unregistered, $session);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I am hoping for my `$unregistered` array to be any element from `allSessions` that does not match an element in `$userSessions`. I'll try integrating `continue`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it did not. I have a messy solution working right now and am hoping to refactor. I'll plan to update with that when I have it.

Comment: I took another look and realized I had the array_push() call at the wrong place within the nested braces. It needed to be *after* the inner loop instead of *before* the inner loop. You might try it again now.